# SQL duplicate trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, mysql-workbench

I have simple project for database classes there i have shop database which implement such logic: for each customer in order table we have order with type = 'CART' when customer confirm his order his order change it type to 'ORDER' and we create a new CART for our customer.
Now i want to write trigger that allows me to control that each customer has only one CART.

I write something like this

```
DELIMITER $$
USE `newshop`$$
CREATE
DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`
TRIGGER `newshop`.`cart_check`
BEFORE INSERT ON `newshop`.`order`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE msg VARCHAR(255);
DECLARE count_pn INTEGER;
SELECT count(*) INTO count_pn FROM newshop.order
    where newshop.order.type = NEW.type 
    and NEW.user_id = newshop.order.user_id
    and NEW.type = 'CART' 
    or NEW.type = 'cart' 
    LIMIT 1;
if count_pn > 0 THEN
BEGIN
    set msg = 'Oh no';
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = msg;
end;
ELSE
BEGIN
    set msg = 'Oh yeah';
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = msg;
END;
END IF;
END$$
```

then when i try to insert into table new order with type cart for user with id = 1, that already has a cart - this trigger doesn't allow me to do this and if i try to add a cart for another user, that doesn't have cart - this trigger also doesn't allow me to do this.

Comment: I'm thinking that there might have been a a question in there somewhere. Maybe there was, and maybe I just missed it. It appears this trigger will always throw an exception, which will cause the INSERT statement to fail. If you want the INSERT to happen, you need to AVOID throwing an exception (i.e. don't execute a `SIGNAL SQLSTATE` statement.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In else, you also have the **SIGNAL SQLSTATE=45000**, which is unhandled exception, it will cause return as failed.

```
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = msg;
```